# 404 - Trying to acess socket.io over nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, plex

I am very lost at the moment, so much so that I actually signed up because of my problem. So here we go: I am running a System with Plex and I am trying to get a node.js Backend with socket.io to work that is running behind Nginx. 
The proxy pass for my HTML (I am using `ejs` to be precise, not sure if relevant) hosted via express works like a charm. But I get a 404 error when my website tries to connect to my backend via socket.io.

My Nginx directives as configured via Plex:

```
location = / {

    proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:50090;
}

location /socket.io/ {
    proxy_http_version      1.1;

    proxy_set_header        Upgrade                 $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header        Connection              "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:50090/socket.io/;
}
```

My client connecting to the backend:

```
var socket = io.connect('https://subdomain.mydomain.com', {secure: true});
```

My Backend listening:

```
const app = express();

const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(http);

http.listen(50090, "127.0.0.1");
```

There is a lot about this on the internet, but it seems like I tried everything by now and nothing worked. Likely because I am very new to this.

Comment: I would recommend you to try it on your pc without nginx to make sure it works as expected. On the client use `var socket = io();` it should connect to the same url as you have in the address in your browser.

Comment: Without nginx  everything works fine. I tried var socket = io(); but it did not make a difference, though I will keep it in mind for the future. Thanks for your Input.